# Определить количество пешек, которые находятся под боем коня

Tags: алгоритм, олимпиада

Есть задача:

> На шахматной доске размерностью N x N находятся пешки и конь.
>   Определить, количество пешек, которые находятся под боем коня при
>   заданном расположении фигур. Пешки в массиве обозначены как 1, конь -
>   2, свободная клетка - 0.

Пример входных данных:

```
5
1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0
0 2 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 0
```

Пример выходных данных:

```
5
```

Вопрос никак не связан с кодом, прошу помощи понять, как это можно сделать. Намекните, у кого есть предположения, пожалуйста.
Как я понял, нужно после инициализации просматривать координаты текущей клетки и сравнивать с заранее созданным массивом "битых" конём клеток. Как тогда его заполнить? Путаница в голове. Может брать координату каждого коня и восемь раз сравнивать с "битой" координатой?

Comment: Посчитать надо за один ход или за несколько?

Comment: @entithat Не сказано в условии. Как я понял, нужно просто вывести количество пешек.

Comment: Тогда просто надо рассматривать поле как двумерный массив и проверять каждый ход буквой Г коня на наличие пешки.

Comment: @entithat Ход буквой Г - это координата коня минус 2 от строки минус 1 от столбца и т. д.? проверять 8 раз или есть какая-то логическая операция?

Comment: Проще проверить 8 раз, мне кажется не выйдет проще.

Comment: @Max Вы на каком языке работаете?

Comment: @Harry олимпиадный C++

Comment: @Max а чем он отличается от неолимпиадного?О_о

Comment: @Harry нужно было набрать минимальное к-во символов чтобы отправить комментарий

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> находятся пешки и конь

Если не очепятка и конь действительно один - то надо просто найти все 8 клеток, находящихся под боем (естественно, с проверкой выхода за границы доски), и посмотреть, что в них - если 1, то увеличивать счетчик :)

Получаем O(1).

Если много и тех, и других - то я бы *при считывании* считал, кого меньше, и играл от них. Но при этом есть тонкость - одна пешка может быть под боем несколькими конями.

На С++ примерно

```
int N, knightR, knightC;
cin >> N;

vector<vector<int>> board(N,vector<int>(N,0));
for(int row = 0; row < N; ++row)
for(int col = 0; col < N; ++col)
{
    cin >> board[row][col];
    if (board[row][col] == 2)
    {
        knightR = row;
        knightC = col;
    }
}
int dr[] = { -2, -2, -1, -1,  1,  1,  2,  2 };
int dc[] = { -1,  1,  2, -2,  2, -2,  1, -1 };
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
{
    int r = knightR+dr[i];
    int c = knightC+dc[i];
    if (r < 0 || r >= N || c < 0 || c >= N) continue;
    if (board[r][c] == 1) count++;
}
cout << count << endl;
```

Comment: Ну еще коня нужно найти)

Comment: @yolosora А вы все равно считывате все поля доски - что тут искать? 8-\ Посмотреть, когда считана двойка?

Comment: @Harry считать 8 битых координат?

Comment: @Harry ну кстати если конь один, то не обязательно все поля доски читать :D

Comment: @yolosora В принципе - *возможно*, да. Но это будет сложнее, чем прочесть все и не мучиться :)